# Why does my screen go blank when I invoke a modal?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I created some buttons within a grid (which I wanted to determine the size dynamically), and now I'm trying to open dialogs/modals, but I don't know why It does not work. I have my REPL link to use, but I will also be sharing my files here.

[REPL_FirstApp](https://svelte.dev/repl/ed4ceeddab824be3971a1993dfc8c119?version=4.2.12)

main_app.svelte

```
<script>
    import SwContainer from './swContainer.svelte';
    import SwButtonIten from './swButtonIten.svelte';
    import SwDialogIten from './swDialogIten.svelte';

    let componentPositions = [
        { 
            component: SwButtonIten,
            props: { cstmLabel: 'Open Dialog 1', handleClick: openDialog1 },
            rowPos: 0,
            colPos: 0
        },
        { 
            component: SwButtonIten,
            props: { cstmLabel: 'Open Dialog 2' },
            rowPos: 0,
            colPos: 1
        }
    ];

    let dialog1IsOpen = false;
    let dialog2IsOpen = false;

    function openDialog1() {
        dialog1IsOpen = true;
    }

    function openDialog2() {
        dialog2IsOpen = true;
    }
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>About</title>
    <meta name="description" content="About this app" />
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
</svelte:head>

<SwContainer numRow={2} numCol={2} {componentPositions}></SwContainer>

<SwDialogIten bind:isOpen={dialog1IsOpen} title="Dialog_1" message="etc, etc, etc" />
<SwDialogIten bind:isOpen={dialog2IsOpen} title="Diálog_2" message="etc, etc, etc" />
```

Another question I have is, what is the best way to invoke a component within another component through the parent class? In my case, I am passing the components that I want to be created through an array. But I don't know if this is the best approach for this!

swContainer.svelte

```
<script>
    import { Col, Container, Row } from 'sveltestrap';
    import SwButtonIten from './swButtonIten.svelte';

    export let uniqueID = 0;
    export let numRow = 0;
    export let numCol = 0;
    export let componentPositions;

</script>

<Container>
    {#each Array(numRow) as _, rowIndex}
        <Row>
            {#each Array(numCol) as _, colIndex}
                <Col>
                    {#each componentPositions.filter(pos => pos.rowPos === rowIndex && pos.colPos === colIndex) as item}
                        <svelte:component this={item.component} {...item.props} />
                    {/each}
                </Col>
            {/each}
        </Row>
    {/each}
</Container>
```

swButtonIten.svelte

```
<script>
    import { Button } from 'sveltestrap';

    export let uniqueID = '';
    export let cstmLabel = '';
    export let rowPos = 0;
    export let colPos = 0;

    export let handleClick;

    function onClick() {
        handleClick();
    }
</script>

<Button on:click={onClick}>{cstmLabel}</Button>
```

swDialogIten.svelte

```
<script>
    import {
        Button,
        Modal,
        ModalBody,
        ModalFooter,
        ModalHeader
    } from 'sveltestrap';

    export let isOpen = false;
    export let title = '';
    export let message = '';
</script>

<Modal bind:isOpen>
    <ModalHeader>{title}</ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>{message}</ModalBody>
    <ModalFooter>
        <Button color="secondary" on:click={() => isOpen = false}>Close</Button>
    </ModalFooter>
</Modal>

<style>
    /* styles */
</style>
```

It turns out that if I run the code this way, when I click the button, the screen just goes dark and I can't do anything else! I have to close the page and open it again

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum, so your history and state of mind aren't relevant information. Also, ask just one question per post.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I hadn't really taken the tour, I was just told about this tool to get help and I looked for it. Do you think it would be better to remove this post and make a new one?

Comment: No. It's perfectly salvageable. I've started revisions for you. Carry on with them as needed.